# CodeIgniter not working with multiple level subfolders for both controllers and views

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty, directory-structure

I am working in Codeigniter with smarty templates.

Problem is that if i go about 2nd subfolder in view or controller, the Codeigniter stops working...

e-g here

```
application/controllers/main.php  - works
application/controllers/admin/dashboard.php - works
application/controllers/admin/manageUsers/ListUsers.php - not working
```

I have searched the web, and they said that i can work with routes, which might do work with controller..

but it is views that i am concern of..
i mean admin views should go under admin folder, but i can not create subfolder in admin, if i put all views in admin folder, it will be a mess, nothing organized. i hope you are understanding what i am trying to say.

e-g

```
themes/default/views/home.tpl - works
themes/default/views/admin/dashboard.tpl works
themes/default/views/admin/site_settings/preferences.tpl not working
```

please can anyone guide me how to fix these issues.

Comment: Are you using a template library? the folder structure of view files seems odd to me.

Comment: In your `admin` controller, are you doing `function admin($site_settings, $preferences)`;

Comment: Did you try editing the `config/route.php` file and adding `$route['admin/(.*)'] = 'admin/$1';`? The other way is to add a `Custom_Router` which extends `CI_Router` and change `require/include` logic there. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is quite common. I've had it when I started working with CodeIgniter as well. What I found out to be the best way to overcome it, was to create a `Custom_Router`, which extends the `CI_Router` class. Doing that allows you to overwrite the controller class include/require logic and allow the usage of subdirs. This is a working example:

```
<?php

class Custom_Router extends CI_Router
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function _validate_request($segments)
    {
        if (file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$segments[0].EXT))
        {
            return $segments;
        }

        if (is_dir(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$segments[0]))
        {
            $this->set_directory($segments[0]);
            $segments = array_slice($segments, 1);

            while(count($segments) > 0 && is_dir(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->directory.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$segments[0]))
            {
                // Set the directory and remove it from the segment array
                $this->directory = $this->directory . $segments[0] .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
                $segments = array_slice($segments, 1);
            }


            if (count($segments) > 0)
            {
                if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->fetch_directory().$segments[0].EXT))
                {
                    show_404($this->fetch_directory().$segments[0]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->set_class($this->default_controller);
                $this->set_method('index');

                if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->fetch_directory().$this->default_controller.EXT))
                {
                    $this->directory = '';
                    return array();
                }

            }

            return $segments;
        }

        show_404($segments[0]);
    }
}

?>
```

The code above works fine with as many subdirs as you'd want, although I wouldn't advice using this approach. I usually specifically state the path to my controllers in the `route.php` file.

Regarding your second problem - the templates. I never liked messy code and even messier viewers which contain `<?php echo $something; for(...){}; foreach(){}... ?>` all over the place. For me, that makes the code really hard to read and specially harder to debug. That's why I've been using the [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) template engine. There are tutorials how to get it working in CodeIgniter (I've used [this](https://github.com/bmatschullat/Twig-Codeigniter) one). Once you're done with it, in your controller you would simply need to write:

```
class Login extends Custom_Controller
{
    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     */
    public function index() {
        $data = array();
        $error_message = "Invalid user!";

        if($this->session->getUserId() != null){
            redirect('/welcome');
        }

        // other logic....



        // depending on how you configure twig, this will search for "login.html.twig"
        // in "application/views/". If your file is located somewhere in the subdirs, 
        // you just write the path: 
        //   admin/login.html.twig => application/views/admin/login.html.twig
        $this->twig->display('login.html.twig', $data); 
    }
}
```

If Twig is not an option for you, then you will need to create a new class which extends the `CI_Loader` class and overwrite the `public function view(){}` method.

By the way, if you're creating a web application with a backend, you might find it easier to manage and maintain your code if you separate your applications in different directories. If you choose to go this way, you will need to create `application/public` and `application/admin` folders preserving the directory structure of a CodeIgniter "application". Here are the steps:

1. Create separate applications

   ```
   /applications
   -- public (a standard application directory structure)
   ---- cache
   ---- config
   ---- controllers
   ---- models
   ---- views
   ---- ...
   -- admin (a standard application directory structure)
   ---- cache
   ---- config
   ---- controllers
   ---- models
   ---- views
   ---- ...
   ```
2. Open `/index.php` and change `$application_folder` to point to `applications/public`
3. Create a copy of `/index.php`, name it `backend.php` (or whatever you want). Open the file and change `$application_folder` to point to the `applications/admin` folder.
4. Open `.htaccess` and add a rule to pass all URI starting with `/admin` to `backend.php`

   ```
   # Route admin urls
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} admin([/])?(.*)
   RewriteRule .* backend.php?$1 [QSA,L]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

1. Put [THIS](https://github.com/ollierattue/codeigniter-multi-level-controller-extension/tree/master/core) file into application/core/
2. Filename must be MY_Router.php